# SimpleXML Document PHP add child with tem:tagName

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

i want to generate xml wsdl request that has parameters like `tem:sessionId` but my php code generates `x:sessionId`. i don't know how to convert `x:` to `tem:`

result i need :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
    <x:Header/>
    <x:Body>
        <tem:GetServicesByProvider>
            <tem:sessionId>890925</tem:sessionId>
            <tem:ProviderId>29</tem:ProviderId>
            <tem:mac/>
        </tem:GetServicesByProvider>
    </x:Body>
</x:Envelope>
```

this is my php code

```
private function createXMLRequest($function, $params)
{
    $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement('<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"><x:Header/></x:Envelope>');
    $body = $xml->addChild('Body');
    $f = $body->addChild($function, '');
    foreach ($params as $param) {
        $f->addChild($param['tag'], $param['text']);
    }

    return $xml;
}
```

but it generates this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
<x:Header/>
<x:Body>
    <x:GetServicesByProvider>
        <x:sessionId>890925</x:sessionId>
        <x:ProviderId>29</x:ProviderId>
        <x:mac/>
    </x:GetServicesByProvider>
</x:Body>
</x:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

The SimpleXML `addChild` method ([documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php)) has a third parameter, `$namespace`, which allows you to specify which namespace the element should be in.

The way this works is a little fiddly, because you have to know *both* the local prefix *and* the namespace URI it's targeting.

To write `<tem:sessionID>` in your case, you would use

```
$f->addChild('tem:sessionID', $value, 'http://tempuri.org/');
```

My recommendation is to put the namespace URI in some sort of constant, and then prepend the `'tem:'` to each element you add:

```
define('XMLNS_SOAP', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
define('XMLNS_TEMP', 'http://tempuri.org/');

$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement('<x:Envelope xmlns:x="' . XMLNS_SOAP . '" xmlns:tem="' . XMLNS_TEMP . '"><x:Header/></x:Envelope>');

$body = $xml->addChild('Body');
$f = $body->addChild($function, '');
foreach ($params as $param) {
    $f->addChild('tem:' . $param['tag'], $param['text'], XMLNS_TEMP);
}
```

Comment: when i add `tem:` to `addChild` method it removes `tem:` automatically.

Comment: @543310 Are you sure you're also including the correct namespace URL as the third parameter? I tested this code before I posted it, and it produced exactly the output you want. Try it for yourself here: https://3v4l.org/majj9